# Redefining constants in PHP

Tags: php, constants

Is it possible to redefine a constant in php which was defined by the `define` function? 
I have a class with several constants that contains the user data. I'm trying to use the class for more than one user.

```
define('ALLEGRO_ID', 'id');
define('ALLEGRO_LOGIN', 'login');
define('ALLEGRO_PASSWORD', 'passwd');
define('ALLEGRO_KEY', 'key');
define('ALLEGRO_COUNTRY', 123);

$allegro = new AllegroWebAPI( );                
$allegro -> Login();
```

I did not write this class, but I am using it due to time constraints. I do not know why the creator of this class `defined` the user data rather than using the variables in the instance.

I know that constants should be constant (obviously!), but I'm looking for a trick to redefine them.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be solved another way that is better architecturally.

Comment: constants that contains the user data sounds weird

Comment: Up next: `define(4, 42);`

Comment: Redefining constants means you're basically using a variable, so just stick with variables to begin with.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you have the [runkit extension](http://php.net/manual/book.runkit.php) installed, you can use [`runkit_constant_redefine()`](http://php.net/runkit_constant_redefine):

```
runkit_constant_redefine("name", "value");
```

In most circumstances, however, it would be a better idea to re-evaluate why you're using constants and not something more fitting.

Comment: There's also [uopz](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uopz.php) PHP extension which has similar function: [uopz_redefine](http://php.net/runkit_constant_redefine). `uopz_redefine()` allows one to redefine class constants too.

Comment: defines are only a constant because PHP says they are;  you can undef in C so why not in PHP? The reason to use defines is that you don't have to declare them as global

Answer (score 25):

No, you cannot redefine a constant (except with [runkit_constant_redefine](http://sg.php.net/runkit_constant_redefine)),
that's why is called CONSTANT.

What you are looking for in the class is actually an object variable in array format:-

```
class user
{
  public $user = array();

  function load($user_id)
  {
    // etc
    $this->$user[$user_id] = something_else;
  }
}
```

Comment: In other words, the answer is 'Yes'.

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: Yes.  Longer answer: runkit_constant_redefine.

Comment: Short Answer: You shouldn't. Long answer: You can, but you still shouldn't. Longer Answer: You can with this hack, but you still really shouldn't. What you're looking for is an inconstantly variable constant ;)

Answer (score 20):

In PHP 5.6+, you can import constants, under an alias. Such alias can overwrite an already existing constant.

The following snippet will print `int(5)`:

```
define('ALLEGRO_ID', 3);
define('NEW_ALLEGRO_ID', 5);
use const NEW_ALLEGRO_ID as ALLEGRO_ID;
var_dump(ALLEGRO_ID);
```

Such mechanism could be legitimate in unit test, or other areas where magic behavior is tolerated, but isn't convenient for your use case, where a class to store your user settings would be more useful.

Finally, this behavior allows to create very confusing situations like `use const true as false;`.

Comment: It printed `int(3)` in every version I tried (`7.3.5`, `7.2.18`, `7.2.4`, `7.1.29`, `7.1.0`, `7.0.1`, `7.0.5`, `7.0.4`, `7.0.3`, `7.0.2`, `7.0.1`, `5.6.29`).

Comment: @WesleyGonçalves Thanks for the catch! The snippet missed the "const" keyword.

Answer (score 6):

passing 3rd param as true will help you

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value', true);
print CONSTANT_NAME.PHP_EOL;
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value2');
print CONSTANT_NAME.PHP_EOL;
```

https://ideone.com/oUG5M9

Comment: This is very interesting, however ["Defining case-insensitive constants is deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0."](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 4):

Constants value once defined remains unchanged throughout the program. If you have such a requirement where you want to change the values in future then keep such values in PHP variables.

Comment: PHP 5.6 introduces a use aliasing mechanism making this statement false.