# Error messages set up as different

Tags: php

How would you set an error message in different way. Here is the code:

```
 $error_message .= 'Invalid email';
```

Although I know its not set completely right it can be translated to this code. Here is the code:

```
 $error_message = error_message;
```

How can I display my error message in this fashion? Here is the code:

```
 error_message;
```

How can I set up my error message so I can display it in without the money sign?

Comment: why would you want to display it without the money sign? Doesn't `echo "error message: " . 'Invalid email';` do the trick?

Comment: No its not doing the trick.

Comment: your question seems unclear. pardon but, you dont want it to putand be called in a variable?

Comment: This seems homework-related and it's unclear what was being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably thinking of constants:

https://www.php.net/define

> $error = 'Invalid Email';
>
> define("error_message", $error);
>
> echo error_message;

"without the money sign" will cause php to attempt to identify a constant by the given value. You may want to read on the general use of [constants](https://www.php.net/constants) before using them as it may be more beneficial to just use localized variables, depending on your needs.

Comment: How can I set it = to a $error?

Comment: Look at this question and answers. This is why I suggested reading on constants before using them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefine-constants-in-php - you're not really supposed to redefine constants. My answer is more to explain what you have posted. Do you have a reason for wanting to avoid $ in your code?