# Change contents of "config.php" file from ajax / jQuery or from any other php file in same directory

Tags: php, jquery, fopen

I have created a *config.php* file for my project to store basic database and application settings.

My *config.php* contents are as follows :

```
<?php

define("SQL_IP", "127.0.0.1"); // ip address of mysql database 
define("SQL_USER", "root");  // username for connecting to mysql
define("SQL_PWD","root"); // password for connecting to mysql
define("SQL_DATABASE","campus"); // database where you have executed sql scripts

define("WEB_SITE_URL","http://localhost/campus/"); // the url where you installed this script . do not delete last slash  
define("USE_MATH", "no"); // yes , no . if you want to use math symbols , you have to enable it
define("DEBUG_SQL","no"); // enable it , if you want to view sql queries .
define("PAGING","30");  // paging for all grids

define("MAIL_FROM", ""); //  Your mail address 
?>
```

Now I want to change from 
`define("SQL_DATABASE","campus")` 
to 
`define("SQL_DATABASE","campus2");`

How can I do it from sending ajax request or from any php file.

Thanks and regards!!

Comment: You cannot modify the constant once it is set.

Comment: Hava a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefine-constants-in-php

Comment: i was able to resolve this issue by using file operations, this is the logic i used,  1) open config.php and store contents in temp variable, use $handler = strReplace("define("SQL_DATABASE","campus")","define("SQL_DATABASE","campus2")" , $handler);   3) save handler contents back to config.php