# Define constant PHP

Tags: php, constants, multilingual

I have a multi-language script that works like this:

**en.php**

```
define('lang_hello_world', 'Hello World!');
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include('en.php'); echo lang_hello_world; ?>
```

The script works fine and replace the language. But now I need to convert the constant that are stored on MySQL.

The `lang_hello_world` is in MySQL and I need to print converted on the page, how can I do this?

Comment: Please add some explanation - what are you trying to do?

Comment: THe lang_hello_world is already defined on the language file, I need to convert the lang_hello_world that I will get from a table on mysql with the correspondent constant defined on the language file.

Answer (score 0):

In the en.php, you need connect the database and define the value, something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM language_table WHERE language = 'EN' LIMIT 1");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
define('lang_hello_world', $row[0]['lang_hello_world']);
```

Hope can help!

Comment: THe lang_hello_world is already defined on the language file, I need to get the lang_hello_world from the mysql and then convert the correspondent constant of the language file.

Comment: You need to redefine your constant in the language file. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefining-constants-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Use [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).  If `$row['var']` fetched from the database equals `lang_hello_world` then:

```
$val = constant($row['var']);
```

Now `$val` equals `Hello World!` if the English file is loaded.  Or obviously:

```
echo constant($row['var']);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just grab it out of your database before you put it in your constant?

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "passw");
    mysql_select_db("languages");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT lang_hello_world FROM languages");
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    define("lang_hello_world", $fetch['lang_hello_world']);
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Suggesting using `mysql_` functions is like still to trying to sell VHS tapes. It's long deprecated (and dropped in the just release PHP7) and you really shouldn't be "promoting" it anymore. At the very least use a `mysqli_` sample.

Comment: THe lang_hello_world is already defined on the language file, I need to get the lang_hello_world from the mysql and then convert the correspondent constant of the language file.