# PHP is allowing me to redefine a constant within included file

Tags: php, constants

How can this be happening?  It defies the language specs.

```
outer.php
---------
<?php
define("VALUE","OUTER");
echo "Outer = " . VALUE . "<br>\n";
include "inner.php";
echo "Outer = " . VALUE . "<br>\n";
?>

inner.php
---------
<?php
define("VALUE","INNER"); // This should not work!
echo "Inner = " . VALUE . "<br>\n";
?>

result (from loading outer.php):
-------
Outer = OUTER
Inner = INNER
Outer = OUTER
```

Once defined, a constant can't be redefined. At least that's the way it's been for as long as I've known PHP (somewhere around version 3).  I expect to get at most a warning, but the constant would remain "OUTER".

PHP Version 5.6.37, CGI/FastCGI

Incidentally, if I execute the above from CLI, it works correctly. (OUTER,OUTER,OUTER).

Any clues?

Comment: if you load the file `outer.php` it will show you warning. but if you load the file `inner.php` that will work as it's not included any file inside it.

Comment: @tuhin18003 -- I'm only running `outer.php`.  Getting no warning and incorrect behavior.

Comment: its wired, cuz it should not work like this. but still you can do `defined('VALUE')?:define("VALUE","INNER");` in the inner.php

Comment: do you loading your outer.php inside any other file or loading it individually? if you loading it individually and gets the issue then it is your php.ini config which doing this

Comment: @LeoTahk, in my actual use case -- inner is a third party module that I shouldn't need to edit, instead we use `outer.php` to override default behavior by defining the constants.  I know that I could just go into the inner module and recode willy-nilly, but that just breaks the whole point of modularity.

Comment: @tuhin18003, loading outer.php individually.  I can find nothing in php.ini config that remotely claims to modify the behavior of defines.  Nor can I find anything on the web that claims it's possible to do with any combination of php.ini settings.

Comment: read answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefining-constants-in-php , maybe something similar

Comment: @LeoTahk, saw that earlier and checked for any of those extensions.. no joy.  Plus, in the example code above, I'm not using any of those features.  That's live code up there.

Comment: Did you check/invalidate any possible Caches (OPCache / APC / XCache)?. Hard Caching - with high update frequency - could be a reason for this weird behavior since 1. inner.php didn't change as by your comments and 2. the cli does something different (which is probably due to having another/no cache).

Comment: @makadev - No caching is happening.  I noticed this problem with existing, much more complicated, software.  I created the outer/inner above just yesterday to reproduce the problem.  I can add/remove other code inside inner and see the changes immediately.

Comment: faced this issue too. moreover this seems to work different on PHP-FPM vs PHP-CGI.