# PHP Multiple require, same function

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate three pdf files with three different translations

The translations are stored within the directory in the files named by its the language prefix:

```
lang/pl/global.php
lang/en/global.php
lang/de/global.php
```

Translations are then stored within GLOBAL VARIABLES for example:

```
define("SOMEVAR", "SOME VALUE PL"); // for lang/pl/global.php
define("SOMEVAR", "SOME VALUE EN"); // for lang/en/global.php
define("SOMEVAR", "SOME VALUE DE"); // for lang/de/global.php
```

At the end of some function foo() i'm trying to call the same function translate() three times to generate 3 translated pdf files. Before a call I have to require translation from the directory structure listed above. It looks like:

```
require('lang/pl/global.php');
translate('pl');

require('lang/en/global.php');
translate('en');

require('lang/de/global.php');
translate('de');
```

But when I try to print a SOMEVAR global variable from the inside of translate() function it only returns the first prefix translation (SOME VALUE PL) - so in this case it would be 3 times of polish translate (3x SOME VALUE PL). Changing order to en/de/pl results in triple english translate (3x SOME VALUE EN).

I've also tried moving require() to the inside of translate() function but i got no results also.

Any help?

Comment: That's because `define` is used to set a constant, not to create a global variable.

Comment: Constants can only be defined once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining constants in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefining-constants-in-php)

Comment: Got it, i will change define to variables instead of constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is create a global variable which is an array, in which case you would need to do:

```
$selectedLanguages = [];
$selectedLanguages[] = "pl";
$selectedLanguages[] = "en";
$selectedLanguages[] = "de";
```

Then when you want to call it for your requires do:

```
global $selectedLanguages;

foreach($selectedLanguages as $language) {
    require('lang/' . $language . '/global.php');
    // Do stuff with your translation here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i like your solution :)