# Is it possible to redefine some preset formats in PHP's date() function?

Tags: php

We've run into an unexpected issue using PHP's date("c") formatting in PHP 5.3.

The format returns a value that is hostile to the datetime column type in MySQL 5.7 and above.

We never realized we were vulnerable to this issue until we attempted to upgrade our MySQL install and we started getting errors from the DB.

Our use of date("c") is nearly ubiquitous in our PHP code, so we face a dilemma and my team is looking to me to solve.

I want to redefine how PHP returns date("c") permanently for all scripts that run on my servers.  Is there a way to branch the function to redefine this preset?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465155/redefining-constants-in-php

Comment: Why not just update the code? You should really not be using PHP 5.3 any more (multiple years ago), so maybe consider that at the same time.

Comment: Php 5.3 is very old at this point, I suggest you update your PHP version. Though I think it's because of the timezone you get from the ISO 8601 format, as mysql doesn't really deal with timezones in the specific column https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm sure many of you deal with legacy codebases in your jobs where version upgrades aren't as simple as they sound.  That's the case I'm in, so I'm trying to stop the bleeding.  But I appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other comments, PHP 5.3 is [extremely out of date and should no longer be used](https://www.php.net/eol.php). As of the time of writing this comment, support ended almost 5 years ago.

I would suggest upgrading your PHP version as soon as possible to reduce the chances of security issues.

In regards to your issue, I think rather than re-defining the constant (which isn't possible without a custom PHP build) it would make more sense to do a regex find & replace across your codebase.

There are only a few functions that accept date format string, so it shouldn't be too hard to replace them automatically.